# I find no way to set the visibility of the GSuite Marketplace API to PUBLIC

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-apps-marketplace

When I try to publish my app on the Gsuite Marketplace via GCP, I find no way to change the setting 'Visibility'. Event if the app has never been published.
Between the two options (My Domain - Public), My domain is selected and can't be switched to Public, so nobody has access to my app.
Any help?

I've tried to contact the support and find help on forums but no answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

First step, I'd recommend reviewing Choosing [where to publish](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing-overview) to ensure that you've published to the correct location. As noted under [Publish your app](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing-gsm#publish_your_app) ([before you publish](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing-cws#publish_your_app)), your app is reviewed to determine if it meets the requirements for the relevant store. Additionally, your application may also have to undergo [OAuth verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914) (I think this could be the problem) , and [security assessment](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/security-assessment) if it accesses user data, such as Gmail, Drive, Contacts, or Calendar

If your app is [exempt from verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#skip) or if you've already undergone assessment and been approved, and your issue persists, I'd recommend contacting [Marketplace Developer Support](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/devconsole/register), via the below steps, who can assist you with your publishing issue.

1. Navigate to the new Developer Dashboard.
2. Click Contact Us.
3. The Developer Support [contact us form](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support) is displayed.

> > I've tried to contact the support and find help on forums but no answer at all.

How did you contact Google Support? They have many teams and sometimes agents are not aware of the scope of support. Personally I would contact GCP Support first to verify your App in GCP, once they confirm everything is working from their end they need to route the case to GSuite with an Admin Console specialist to debug the problem